# Split large page into multiple A4 pages

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I am printing some custom drawn charts on a fast Reports 4 databand.

The band has one **text** component and one **picture** component which I manipulate in the OnBeforePrint event to draw my charts using its canvas.

The problem is that the width of the charts may change drastically and go far beyond the page width and scaling/streching the charts to fit the page limits is not an option for the user.

I tried to make the page width grow to accommodate the graphics and it worked very well while visualizing, but I cannot print it since the user's printer only accepts A4 paper size.

So how can I split the report in smaller A4 pieces like the following image?

[image: result changing pages width]
[image: Desired result]

PS: the first image is the actual report output and the second one is the desired result.

Comment: You also need to assume that a user may wish to print on other size paper, for example our company has a 60" plotter printer which we use to print things just like this.

Comment: Did you try "Split big pages" for "Print mode" in print dialogue?

Comment: It is exactly what I am looking for Sir Rufo.
But it doesn't work on the preview screen, and the user complain about it.
I'm trying to mimic this splitting on the preview screen.